# Only rotate one axis on Unity gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have inherited some code that simply does this....

`transform.rotation = m.rotation;`

I know that my model will always be standing upright and therefore it only needs to rotate around on one axis. How can I only change the Y rotation.

I can't seem to get this to work because I get stuck right away when I try:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m.rotation.x, m.rotation.y, m.rotation.z);
```

Which does not align it the same as:

```
transform.rotation = m.rotation;
```

I was hoping to then just change the `m.rotation.y`. Any reason this doesn't work?

The `m` value looks like this

```
 public MarkerInfo(string name, bool isVisible, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale){
        this.name = name;
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
        this.position = position;
        this.rotation = rotation;
        this.scale = scale;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `m` stands for a c# class and not a uniy one, changing its rotations will have no effect. You need to apply your rotation to a unity `Transform`, that normally is an instance of a component of a gameobject of the scene. That way you can see in the scene the changes you apply to the transform of that specific gameobject.

I think you need to know what unity gameobject does `MarkerInfo` manipulate or stands for, get its `Transform` with `gameObject.transform` and rotate that.

With [transform.RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) or manipulating directly yout transform's [Transform.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) you should be able to get your rotation.

Take into account that this line: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m.rotation.x, m.rotation.y, m.rotation.z);` you are trying wont do what I think you think it does. The x,y,z of a quaternion are not the euler angles.
To apply that rotation to the transform you need to do  `transform.rotation = m.rotation`, so the fact those line do not do same make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best ways to do this are by using [Quaternion.Euler](https://C#%20Scripting%20API%20Search%20manual...%20VERSION:%202020.3%20Select%20a%20different%20version%20UnityEngine%20UnityEngine.Accessibility%20UnityEngine.AI%20UnityEngine.Analytics%20UnityEngine.Android%20UnityEngine.Animations%20UnityEngine.Apple%20UnityEngine.Assertions%20UnityEngine.Audio%20UnityEngine.CrashReportHandler%20UnityEngine.Diagnostics%20UnityEngine.Events%20UnityEngine.Experimental%20UnityEngine.iOS%20UnityEngine.Jobs%20UnityEngine.LowLevel%20UnityEngine.Lumin%20UnityEngine.Networking%20UnityEngine.ParticleSystemJobs%20UnityEngine.Playables%20UnityEngine.PlayerLoop%20UnityEngine.Profiling%20UnityEngine.Rendering%20UnityEngine.SceneManagement%20UnityEngine.Scripting%20UnityEngine.SearchService%20UnityEngine.Serialization%20UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms%20UnityEngine.Sprites%20UnityEngine.SubsystemsImplementation%20UnityEngine.TestTools%20UnityEngine.TextCore%20UnityEngine.Tilemaps%20UnityEngine.tvOS%20UnityEngine.U2D%20UnityEngine.UIElements%20UnityEngine.VFX%20UnityEngine.Video%20UnityEngine.Windows%20UnityEngine.WSA%20UnityEngine.XR%20Classes%20AccelerationEvent%20AnchoredJoint2D%20AndroidInput%20AndroidJavaClass%20AndroidJavaObject%20AndroidJavaProxy%20AndroidJNI%20AndroidJNIHelper%20Animation%20AnimationClip%20AnimationClipPair%20AnimationCurve%20AnimationEvent%20AnimationInfo%20AnimationState%20Animator%20AnimatorClipInfo%20AnimatorControllerParameter%20AnimatorOverrideController%20AnimatorStateInfo%20AnimatorTransitionInfo%20AnimatorUtility%20Application%20AreaEffector2D%20ArticulationBody%20ArticulationDrive%20ArticulationJacobian%20ArticulationReducedSpace%20AssetBundle%20AssetBundleCreateRequest%20AssetBundleManifest%20AssetBundleRecompressOperation%20AssetBundleRequest%20AsyncOperation%20AudioChorusFilter%20AudioClip%20AudioConfiguration%20AudioDistortionFilter%20AudioEchoFilter%20AudioHighPassFilter%20AudioListener%20AudioLowPassFilter%20AudioRenderer%20AudioReverbFilter%20AudioReverbZone%20AudioSettings%20AudioSource%20Avatar%20AvatarBuilder%20AvatarMask%20Behaviour%20BillboardAsset%20BillboardRenderer%20BitStream%20BoneWeight%20BoneWeight1%20BoundingSphere%20Bounds%20BoundsInt%20BoxcastCommand%20BoxCollider%20BoxCollider2D%20BuildCompression%20BuoyancyEffector2D%20Cache%20CachedAssetBundle%20Caching%20Camera%20Canvas%20CanvasGroup%20CanvasRenderer%20CapsulecastCommand%20CapsuleCollider%20CapsuleCollider2D%20CharacterController%20CharacterInfo%20CharacterJoint%20CircleCollider2D%20Cloth%20ClothSkinningCoefficient%20ClothSphereColliderPair%20ClusterInput%20ClusterNetwork%20Collider%20Collider2D%20ColliderDistance2D%20Collision%20Collision2D%20Color%20Color32%20ColorUtility%20CombineInstance%20Compass%20Component%20CompositeCollider2D%20ComputeBuffer%20ComputeShader%20ConfigurableJoint%20ConstantForce%20ConstantForce2D%20ContactFilter2D%20ContactPoint%20ContactPoint2D%20ControllerColliderHit%20Coroutine%20CrashReport%20Cubemap%20CubemapArray%20CullingGroup%20CullingGroupEvent%20Cursor%20CustomRenderTexture%20CustomRenderTextureManager%20CustomRenderTextureUpdateZone%20CustomYieldInstruction%20Debug%20DetailPrototype%20Display%20DistanceJoint2D%20DrivenRectTransformTracker%20DynamicGI%20EdgeCollider2D%20Effector2D%20Event%20ExitGUIException%20ExposedPropertyResolver%20ExposedReference%3CT0%3E%20FixedJoint%20FixedJoint2D%20Flare%20FlareLayer%20Font%20FrameTiming%20FrameTimingManager%20FrictionJoint2D%20FrustumPlanes%20GameObject%20GeometryUtility%20Gizmos%20GL%20Gradient%20GradientAlphaKey%20GradientColorKey%20Graphics%20GraphicsBuffer%20Grid%20GridBrushBase%20GridLayout%20GUI%20GUIContent%20GUIElement%20GUILayout%20GUILayoutOption%20GUILayoutUtility%20GUISettings%20GUISkin%20GUIStyle%20GUIStyleState%20GUIUtility%20Gyroscope%20Handheld%20Hash128%20HashUnsafeUtilities%20HashUtilities%20HDROutputSettings%20HingeJoint%20HingeJoint2D%20HostData%20HumanBone%20HumanDescription%20HumanLimit%20HumanPose%20HumanPoseHandler%20HumanTrait%20ImageConversion%20Input%20IntegratedSubsystem%20IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor%20Joint%20Joint2D%20JointAngleLimits2D%20JointDrive%20JointLimits%20JointMotor%20JointMotor2D%20JointSpring%20JointSuspension2D%20JointTranslationLimits2D%20JsonUtility%20Keyframe%20LayerMask%20LazyLoadReference%3CT0%3E%20LensFlare%20Light%20LightBakingOutput%20LightingSettings%20LightmapData%20LightmapSettings%20LightProbeGroup%20LightProbeProxyVolume%20LightProbes%20LineRenderer%20LineUtility%20LocalizationAsset%20LocationInfo%20LocationService%20LOD%20LODGroup%20Logger%20MasterServer%20MatchTargetWeightMask%20Material%20MaterialPropertyBlock%20Mathf%20Matrix4x4%20Mesh%20MeshCollider%20MeshFilter%20MeshRenderer%20Microphone%20MonoBehaviour%20Motion%20MovieTexture%20Network%20NetworkMessageInfo%20NetworkPlayer%20NetworkView%20NetworkViewID%20Object%20OcclusionArea%20OcclusionPortal%20ParticleCollisionEvent%20ParticlePhysicsExtensions%20ParticleSystem%20ParticleSystemForceField%20ParticleSystemRenderer%20PatchExtents%20PhysicMaterial%20Physics%20Physics2D%20PhysicsJobOptions2D%20PhysicsMaterial2D%20PhysicsScene%20PhysicsScene2D%20PhysicsSceneExtensions%20PhysicsSceneExtensions2D%20PhysicsUpdateBehaviour2D%20Ping%20Plane%20PlatformEffector2D%20PlayerPrefs%20PlayerPrefsException%20PointEffector2D%20PolygonCollider2D%20Pose%20ProceduralMaterial%20ProceduralPropertyDescription%20ProceduralTexture%20Projector%20PropertyName%20QualitySettings%20Quaternion%20Random%20RangeInt%20Ray%20Ray2D%20RaycastCommand%20RaycastHit%20RaycastHit2D%20Rect%20RectInt%20RectOffset%20RectTransform%20RectTransformUtility%20ReflectionProbe%20RelativeJoint2D%20RemoteSettings%20RenderBuffer%20Renderer%20RendererExtensions%20RenderSettings%20RenderTargetSetup%20RenderTexture%20RenderTextureDescriptor%20Resolution%20ResourceRequest%20Resources%20ResourcesAPI%20Rigidbody%20Rigidbody2D%20RuntimeAnimatorController%20ScalableBufferManager%20Screen%20ScreenCapture%20ScriptableObject%20SecondarySpriteTexture%20Security%20Shader%20ShaderVariantCollection%20SkeletonBone%20SkinnedMeshRenderer%20Skybox%20SleepTimeout%20SliderJoint2D%20Snapping%20Social%20SoftJointLimit%20SoftJointLimitSpring%20SortingLayer%20SparseTexture%20SpherecastCommand%20SphereCollider%20SplatPrototype%20SpringJoint%20SpringJoint2D%20Sprite%20SpriteMask%20SpriteRenderer%20StateMachineBehaviour%20StaticBatchingUtility%20StreamingController%20Subsystem%20SubsystemDescriptor%20SubsystemManager%20SurfaceEffector2D%20SystemInfo%20TargetJoint2D%20Terrain%20TerrainCollider%20TerrainData%20TerrainExtensions%20TerrainLayer%20TextAsset%20TextGenerationSettings%20TextGenerator%20TextMesh%20Texture%20Texture2D%20Texture2DArray%20Texture3D%20Time%20Touch%20TouchScreenKeyboard%20TrailRenderer%20Transform%20Tree%20TreeInstance%20TreePrototype%20UICharInfo%20UILineInfo%20UIVertex%20Vector2%20Vector2Int%20Vector3%20Vector3Int%20Vector4%20WaitForEndOfFrame%20WaitForFixedUpdate%20WaitForSeconds%20WaitForSecondsRealtime%20WaitUntil%20WaitWhile%20WebCamDevice%20WebCamTexture%20WebGLInput%20WheelCollider%20WheelFrictionCurve%20WheelHit%20WheelJoint2D%20WindZone%20WWW%20WWWForm%20YieldInstruction%20Interfaces%20Enumerations%20Attributes%20Assemblies%20UnityEditor%20Unity%20Other%20Quaternion.normalized), which converts a Vector3 to a Quaternion (Unity's confusing variable for storing rotation), or by using [Quaternion.Set](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Set.html), which sets the values of a Quaternion similar to Vector3.Set. The first one has 2 declarations: 1 where you pass a vector3 variable, and another where you pass 3 ints/floats. The following 2 lines of code both do the same thing using both declarations.

```
transform.rotation += Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up);
transform.rotation += Quaternion.Euler(0, 1, 0);
```

The second method works like this (I don't know what the fourth one does, but it's typically 1):

```
// transform.Set(x, y, z, 1);

transform.Set(0, 45, 0, 1);
transform.Set(transform.x + 1, transform.y, transform.z, 1);
```

Quaternions are confusing and annoying at first, but Unity comes with a lot of fancy rotation-focused functions that coultn't be possible without them. You can use Quaternion.Euler to convert a Vector3 to a Quaternion and then use those functions on them. They could come in handy later. You can find them [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) under "public/static methods".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want player to have same forward vector as other object but keep the original up vector?

I would avoid Euler Angles as much as possible because they are "glitchy" and try like that:

```
var forward = m.forward;
forward.y = 0;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, Vector3.up);
```

just resolve the case

```
m.forwad == Vector3.down || m.forward == Vector3.up
```

and it should be working